# Automatically updating Doxygen documentation and making it readily available to users with CMake

Tags: cmake, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have worked on multiple C++ libraries that are built with CMake and run Doxygen to generate HTML documentation. In every one of these libraries, the documentation get's built into an "html" folder in the CMake "build" directory and never gets looked at by anyone.

*Because let's be honest, most people don't like to read documentation at all - let alone search for it.*

This leads to a few questions:

1. Is there a standard location to install the documentation once it is built where it makes it very clear to users that documentation is available for a library?
2. How can I ensure that every time my library is built, the documentation will be **automatically** updated and installed in this standard location?
3. Is there any standard way to keep past versions of documentation for reference in case someone is using an earlier version of the library?

Comment: regarding 2) I think this update can be done by making the generation of the documentation part of the building of the executable, so if the executable is rebuild the documentation is build as well. Regarding 3) When the code is stored in a repository checking out this version and building the documentation (probably with the original doxygen version) should be sufficient.

Comment: @albert, I already have these projects set up to automatically build the documentation with each build, but the issue is the documentation goes in the "build" directory where no one will see it. There doesn't seem to be a standard location to put it so users of the library will always know where it is.

Comment: In point 1) the standard place issue is addressed. but, as far as I know, there is no standard place. The return question is where does the resulting lib reside?  When the later question is answered, probably, a solution for  the documentation can be found. Regarding point 2 the presupposition for me is that point 1 has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html)

> **4.11.3. Specific Options**
>   The following directories, or symbolic links to directories, must be in /usr/share, if the corresponding subsystem is installed:
>   **Directory Description**
>   ...
>   *doc*   Miscellaneous documentation (optional)

2) I would say, you can add to the install target a command to copy the doxygen in ***prefix*/usr/share/doc**

Also having the doxygen in the build dir first, seems ok IMHO.

3) Usually with a distro having a package manager you can create a doc package so user who want "past" doc just need to get the package doc having the same revision than the binary package...

note: on Archlinux doc is shipped with the library, on Debian like you have package-doc, same for homebrew IIRC

note: you can also configure doxygen so the error message generated can be parsed by your ide (e.g. QtCreator) like regular gcc error so you can see them in the error log at each build.

Comment: Thanks @Mizux, That is very useful info. I will try to set it up so an "Install" command puts the docs in some sensible location like that. Still not sure where to put it for a Windows install though... Maybe I'll just put a doc folder in the main install folder for the project.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two very different issues:

A. Developers building the software don't even know about the doxygen part of the build they're using

B. Regular users don't know there is documentation available either (from doxygen or else)

B. is not really a technical question so I'll be focusing on developers. First you should make the doxygen part of the build "opt-out", I mean enabled by default. Just use a regular (and fake) cmake dependency for that; in other words lie to cmake and pretend that building doxygen is required to build the library. In the doxygen rule/command, use the cmake COMMENT feature with something like this: COMMENT "doxygen building documention in ${DOXYOUT}". As it usually takes a while, developers will notice. At the very end of the build use a cmake message "Reminder, you just built documentation in ${DOXYOUT}"

Now back to your more specific questions:

1. No standard location but see above instead.
2. See above.
3. Use a regular version control repository and check in the doxygen output folder(s) every time you do a release. This can be part of your release automation.

Also have a look at https://readthedocs.org/

Comment: I really like the idea of using something like readthedocs.org, but it expects you to use Sphinx to generate the documentation and doesn't seem to natively support Doxygen.

Comment: And for some additional info - I do have it set up to build the docs automatically every time a build is run, so the developer doesn't really need to know it's happening. I think what I'm missing is what needs to be done with the docs in the "install" step.

Comment: OK I think I'm starting to understand the question better. Maybe you too ;-) As of now the keyword "install" is not ONCE in the question! I strongly suggest some rephrasing then.

Comment: You're right, I should have said "installed" in a standard location instead of just placed haha. That would be more clear. I've updated the question.